# Comparings multiple parts of a string with separating characters `"` between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two tables with strings. Now, those strings consists of different parts seperated by an `"`. For example:

table1:

```
---------------------
| 1 | hello"world   |
---------------------
| 2 | hows"life"bro |
---------------------
```

table2:

```
-----------------------
| 1 | world"hello     |
-----------------------
| 2 | hows"bro"life   |
-----------------------
```

At the moment I got a query like this:

`select * from table1 inner join table2
on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.colum2 = table2.colum2`

The query I need should show both rows, because if you change the `hello` and the `world` from table1 you get `world"hello` which table2 does contain. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it always separated by `"` ?

Comment: @Prdp yes it is always seperated by `"`

Answer (score 1):

You need a split string function to do this

```
;WITH tab1
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES ( 1,'hello"world' ),
                        (2,'hows"life"bro' )) t1 (id, NAME)
                CROSS apply (SELECT *
                             FROM   Delimitedsplit8k(t1.NAME, '"')) cs),
     tab2
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES ( 1,'world"hello' ),
                        (2,'hows"bro"life' )) t2 (id, NAME)
                CROSS apply (SELECT *
                             FROM   Delimitedsplit8k(t2.NAME, '"')) cs)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,
                t1.NAME,
                t2.id,
                t2.NAME
FROM   tab1 t1
       JOIN tab2 t2
         ON t1.Item = t2.Item
```

Create the split string from here

[Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `column2` to `xml` and use `xquery` to sort the values and compare.

```
declare @T1 table (id int, col varchar(max))
insert into @T1 (id, col) values (1, 'hellow"world'), (2, 'a"b"c')

declare @T2 table (id int, col varchar(max))
insert into @T2 (id, col) values (1, 'world"hellow'), (2, 'b"c"a')

select *
from @T1 as t1
inner join @T2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where 
    cast('<a>' + replace(t1.col, '"', '</a><a>') + '</a>' as xml).query('for $x in /a order by $x return string($x)').value('/', 'varchar(max)') =
    cast('<a>' + replace(t2.col, '"', '</a><a>') + '</a>' as xml).query('for $x in /a order by $x return string($x)').value('/', 'varchar(max)')
```