# Illigal qualified name character with XML parsing into SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am trying to filter a column in my table using a query with XML parsing. This query is made into C# and I'm using SQLDataAdapter to perform the query. My code is the following:

```
string sqlstring = $@"select * from [AS_GOV_PS_oud] inner join [AS_GOV_PStest13_1_2017v2]
                        on   
                                [AS_GOV_PStest13_1_2017v2].[I/O name]        = 'ST' where
cast('<a>' + replace([AS_GOV_PS_oud].Interconnection, '\""', ' </ a >< a > ') + ' </ a > ' as xml).query('for $x in / a order by $x return string($x)').value(' / ', 'varchar(max)') =                            
cast('<a>' + replace([AS_GOV_PStest13_1_2017v2].Interconnection, '\""', ' </ a >< a > ') + ' </ a > ' as xml).query('for $x in / a order by $x return string($x)').value(' / ', 'varchar(max)') ";

string cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Scratchpad"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cn))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlstring, myConnection);
            }
```

The error code is the following:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: XML parsing: line 1, character 33, illegal qualified name character

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server to get SQL statements working before using in C#.  The error messages in SSMS are much better than c#.

Comment: @jdweng, this tells me exactly the same: `XML parsing: line 1, character 33, illegal qualified name character`

Comment: Need to see the actual string after variable substitution.

Comment: What character is at position 33, in line 1, after variable substitution?

Comment: @jdweng and @MattJones ofcourse, here is the string after substitution: `cast('<a>' + replace([AS_GOV_PS_oud].Interconnection, '\"', ' </ a >< a > ') + ' </ a > ' as xml).query('for $x in / a order by $x return string($x)').value(' / ', 'varchar(max)') =                            
cast('<a>' + replace([AS_GOV_PStest13_1_2017v2].Interconnection, '\"', ' </ a >< a > ') + ' </ a > ' as xml).query('for $x in / a order by $x return string($x)').value(' / ', 'varchar(max)') `

Comment: Does that mess look like a SQL Query String?

Comment: @jdweng I updated the question with the actual strings after the substitution ^^

Comment: String concatenation to generate SQL queries is the mother of all SQL Injections and conversion errors. Don't do it. The query string is unreadable anyway. Create a view from it instead and use parameterized queries

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  I would put string into a query window on SSMS and see what error is returned.

Comment: @jdweng *I don't see anything obvious* ... That's true, because blanks are invisible characters :-)

Comment: @wouterdejong I just found your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41638948/5089204) and have a much better understanding, what you want. But the main question is: Why is there CSV-data in one column? **This is breaking 1NF**... If you do not have a good reason for this, you should either store this in real XML or - depending on your needs - in a related side-table. Putting more than one value in one column is a huge design flaw...

Comment: @wouterdejong: Btw: Your idea to join this as a sorted string would break, if one element can exist more than once. Just imagine `A"B"C` on one table and `B"A"C"A` in the second. Same values, but `ABC` will not be equal to `AABC`... CSV-data tends to be murky...

Comment: @wouterdejong And one more thing to think about: If the separated values could - by any chance - include forbidden characters like `<, > or &` or many special (not plain latin) characters (like `This"is"fobidden & ugly"don't do it`) the simple XML split will crash...

Comment: @Shnugo Also it seems like it doenst works without an `"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is super ugly!

With this you break almost any rule how one should do this. But nevertheless your question can be answered: **blanks in the wrong place**

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST('<a>test</a>' AS XML) --works

SELECT CAST('< a>test</a>' AS XML) --exception due to the blank in '< a>'

SELECT CAST('<a>test</ a>' AS XML) --exception due to the blank in '</ a>'
```

My suggestion: Think about the whole thing once again... What are you really trying to achieve? Using such a construction as condition for a join is an incredibly wrong approach...

Re-Think it and place a new quesiton, where you set up some sample data, describe your needs and provide the expected output.

Place a link to this question and - if you follow [these sugggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/5089204) - SO's armada will rush in and will help you to find a better solution than this...

Comment: I just had a similar issue. In my case, I copy/pasted working TSQL into C# code. The TSQL contained double quotes. The paste then completely ruined the text. I had to replace double quotes -> double double quotes before pasting so that the formatting would be correctly retained. Visual Studio inserted unwanted spaces and newlines.